# How is the order of items managed by Python's heapq library determined?

Tags: python, python-2.7, heap

I was under the impression that the first value was what determined a values position in the heap, however that doesn't seem to be the case.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import heapq

q = []
heapq.heappush(q, (10, 11))
heapq.heappush(q, (11, 12))
heapq.heappush(q, (9, 10))
print(q)
```

This gives me an output of

```
[(9, 10), (11, 12), (10, 11)]
```

However I was expecting an output like

```
[(9, 10), (10, 11), (11, 12)]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition on `heapq` is not a "sort guarantee" over the provided list. Instead, it guarantees `q[k] <= q[2*k+1]` and `q[k] <= q[2*k+2]` (using `q` as in your example).

This is due that it is managed internally as a binary tree.

If you simply expect to use the sorted list, you can use the `heappop` as [shown here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html?highlight=heap#basic-examples). In your specific example you could:

```
sorted_q = [heappop(q) for i in range(len(q))
```

and the result, as you expected, will be:

```
>>> print sorted_q
[(9, 10), (10, 11), (11, 12)]
```

---

The theory is explained [here in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html?highlight=heap#theory). Relevant is the following line:

> The interesting property of a heap is that a[0] is always its smallest element.

Which is a direct result of the condition `q[k] <= q[2*k+1]` and `q[k] <= q[2*k+2]`, which is a condition of the heap.

However, there are no further guarantees about the order on the rest of the array. And, in fact, both following trees are valid heaps:

```
    0
 1     2
2 5   3 4
```

and

```
    0
 2     1
5 3   4 2
```

Which are stored, respectively, as

```
[0, 1, 2, 2, 5, 3, 4]
```

and

```
[0, 2, 1, 5, 3, 4, 2]
```