# heapify function does not give sorted list

Tags: heap, python-3.7

How does `heapq.heapify()` work?
I am trying to find the median using heap.
`heapify` returns me a sorted way
when I add element using `heapq.heappush()` using it is inserted in a list.
When I call heapify again the list returned is not sorted.

```
import heapq

l=[5,15,1,3]

heapq.heapify(l)

print(l)
```

This gives me `[1, 3, 5, 15]`

But when I add `heapq.heappush(l,2)`
it returns

```
[1, 2, 5, 15, 3]
```

when I do the again `heapq.heapify(l)`

Still, it gives me the same.

```
[1, 2, 5, 15, 3]
```

How can we achieve to find median using the heap? Should the list be sorted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is the order of items managed by Python's heapq library determined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36479149/how-is-the-order-of-items-managed-by-pythons-heapq-library-determined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have a look at the [theory section of `heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#theory) you will find that it does not sort your list. but it puts them in an oder with a *strange invariant*:

```
lst[k] <= lst[2*k+1] and lst[k] <= lst[2*k+2]
```

this is satisfied for your list; if you look at it in 'binary tree' form:

```
      1
  2       5
15  3
```

`2` is smaller than `15` and `3`. which satisfies the condition. `5` is compared to non-existing elements (which are considered to be infinite - therefore the condition holds).

---

in order to sort your list you best use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
lst = sorted(lst)
# [1, 3, 5, 15]
```

and to then *efficiently* insert in an already sorted list the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#module-bisect) module:

```
from bisect import insort_left
insort_left(lst, 2)
# [1, 2, 3, 5, 15]
```

---

the median is now at `lst[len(lst)//2]`.

```
print(f"median = {lst[len(lst)//2]}")
# median = 3
```

or, depending on your convention (here the one used in [`statistics.median`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.median)):

```
def median(lst):
    ln = len(lst)
    if ln % 2 != 0:
        return lst[ln // 2]
    else:
        return (lst[ln // 2 - 1] + lst[ln // 2]) / 2
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want the sorted list after adding elements each time, try adding those elements to the list(append them). Then heapify the list as you did. It would give you the sorted list each time. :-)

Comment: no. that is not what heapify does. and the OP tried heapify after appending and that did not work.